# Can Mac OS X and Windows 7 share the same HDD?

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive

I'm deciding to build a Hackintosh that the OS X will be installed on a 120Gb SSD while my Windows 7 will be on another 120Gb SSD.

However I just have one 1Tb HDD which I used to store the non-system files of my Windows 7.

My question is can my newly installed OS X store data onto that HDD which is now being used by my Windows 7?

Comment: [Hackintosh questions are considered off topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed). Also, this question has been asked and answered *many* times for the general (non-Hackintosh) case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I believe you can read files on a NTFS partition with a Mac running OSX. But writing to a NTFS file system may be a bit more problematic. I hear it can be done but it's not exactly easy/simple. (It's even harder, if not impossible, for Windows to read/write to the HFS file system which is what OSX uses. Maybe there's a utility/patch/driver to do this but I've not heard of it.)

That's why I usually recommend preparing any shared drive (partition) to use the FAT32 file system since FAT32 is pretty universal - especially when it's plugged into a USB port (hint, hint). Only problem is, FAT32 is limited to 4Gb file sizes on a 2.1Tb partition which could be a problem if you deal with large files such as video.

(Hint: If you only need occasional access to your shared files then you might want a way to keep your hard drive off when it's not being accessed and thus save any wear and tear on the drive. That's why I suggest connecting it to a USB port using something like a USB-to-SATA/PATA adapter.)

But in your case, it may be better if you could use that 1Tb drive in a dedicated file server on your own LAN. But obviously, that would require a second computer or another LAN device like a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/products/professionals/drobo/). I can't say if that's an option but the ability to access files with other systems from Android to PS3/XBox or whatever might be incentive.